# remove duplicate and take last occurence of column value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have below query which is generating duplicate result for `H_POSAL_ID` as `H_POSAL_ID` can change `H_KACCT_ID` in time:

```
SELECT
  'XXX',
  'JP',
  ACC.H_KACCT_BK,
  LACC.H_KACCT_ID,
  HSAL.H_POSAL_BK,
  LACC.H_POSAL_ID
FROM DRD_ORD LACC
INNER JOIN TRC_ORD ACC
ON LACC.H_KACCT_ID   =ACC.H_KACCT_ID
AND LACC.SYS_DB_NAME =ACC.SYS_DB_NAME
AND ACC.SYS_DB_NAME    ='JP'
INNER JOIN H_SALES HSAL
ON LACC.H_POSAL_ID     = HSAL.H_POSAL_ID
AND LACC.SYS_DB_NAME   = HSAL.SYS_DB_NAME
AND HSAL.SYS_DB_NAME    ='JP'
WHERE LACC.SYS_DB_NAME ='JP'
and LACC.H_POSAL_ID = 302774;
```

Result:

[image]

I want to take only the last occurence of `H_POSAL_ID` vs `H_KACCT_ID`

Comment: Do you have a separate timestamp or date column to get the last occurrence of h_posal_id?

Comment: actually i dont want to take the timestamp or date column but want to take the last occurence of H_POSAL_ID means i belive i have to use MAX function for the same ?

Comment: Which of the two records in the result you have displayed are you looking for? Max on which column?

Comment: Max on H_POSAL_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below SQL , it contains additional condition in where clause which gives max H_KACCT_ID for each H_POSTAL_ID. There can be other way to write this by using a sub query instead of using additional condition in where.

```
SELECT
  'XXX',
  'JP',
  ACC.H_KACCT_BK,
  LACC.H_KACCT_ID,
  HSAL.H_POSAL_BK,
  LACC.H_POSAL_ID
FROM DRD_ORD LACC
INNER JOIN TRC_ORD ACC
ON LACC.H_KACCT_ID   =ACC.H_KACCT_ID
AND LACC.SYS_DB_NAME =ACC.SYS_DB_NAME
AND ACC.SYS_DB_NAME    ='JP'
INNER JOIN H_SALES HSAL
ON LACC.H_POSAL_ID     = HSAL.H_POSAL_ID
AND LACC.SYS_DB_NAME   = HSAL.SYS_DB_NAME
AND HSAL.SYS_DB_NAME    ='JP'
WHERE LACC.SYS_DB_NAME ='JP'
and (LACC.H_POSAL_ID, LACC.H_KACCT_ID) IN (SELECT H_POSAL_ID, MAX(H_KACCT_ID) H_KACCT_ID from DRD_ORD group by H_POSAL_ID)
and LACC.H_POSAL_ID = 302774;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could number rows in proper order using `row_number()` and take only first rows for each `h_posal_id`, like here:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/WQJ92459)</sup>**

```
select h_kacct_bk, h_kacct_id, h_posal_bk, h_posal_id
  from (select h_kacct_bk, h_kacct_id, h_posal_bk, h_posal_id,
               row_number() over (partition by h_posal_id order by h_kacct_id desc)  rn
          from t)
  where rn = 1
```

You can also use `max() keep dense rank...` or `last_value()` or find max values of `h_kacct_id` for each `h_posal_id` in subquery. But `row_number()` seems to be more compact and readable.